# Firebird query with 2 aliases returns empty dataset

Tags: sql, firebird

I have the following tables in my database:
3 master tables, 1 detail table and 1 table for "1 to many" relation.

3 master tables are:

**Employees**: id, first_name, last_name

**Positions**: id, name, abbr

**regions**: id, name

and

**r_employees_positions**: id, employee_id, position_id.  It's table for "1 to many" relations with "Employees" and "Positions":

detail table is:

**Partners**: id, partner_name, distributor_id, operator_id, position_id, region_id

My aim is get dataset like this:

**id, Partner_name, distributor, operator, region**

The "Employees" table has 2 aliases in query: "distr" and "oper". "distr" I used for get info who distributes partner's order, "oper" is used for get info about responsible person for orders accuracy.

this select statement returns empty dataset:

```
Select 
 p.id, p.partner_name,
 distr.first_name||' '||distr.Last_name as distibutor,  
 oper.first_name||' '||oper.Last_name as operator
from partners p, employees distr, employees oper, positions pos,
      r_employees_positions ep
where
 (p.partgrp_id=pg.partgrp_id) and
 (p.distributor_id=distr.id and distr.id=ep.employee_id and 
                        ep.position_id=pos.id) and     
 (p.operator_id=oper.id and oper.id=ep.employee_id and 
                        ep.position_id=pos.id
```

What is wrong in my select statement?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including the sample data that produce the incorrect results, and the expected results for that sample data. Also, I highly recommend you to stop using SQL-89 style implicit joins, and instead switch to SQL-92 style explicit join.

Comment: I would said "everything is wrong with this statement" starting from using ANSI89 join that hides the fact of diamond relationship. Record in r_employees_positions obviously cannot satisfy both conditions at once.

Comment: Answers belong in answer posts & not in question posts. But code-only answers are poor, explain why/how it is answer. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this:

```
Select 
 p.*,
 pg.partgrp,
 distr.first_name||' '||distr.Last_name as distibutor,  
 oper.first_name||' '||oper.Last_name as operator,      
 r.name as region
from partners p, partnersgroups pg, employees distr, employees oper, positions pos,  
    r_employees_positions ep
where
 (p.partgrp_id=pg.partgrp_id) and
 (
     (p.position_id=distr.id and distr.id=ep.employee_id and ep.position_id=pos.id) 
 OR
     (p.operator_id=oper.id and oper.id=ep.employee_id and ep.position_id=pos.id)
 )
```